# Powershell handle two variables based on the same name, like SQL join

Tags: powershell, powercli, esxi

My first variables, is someting like:

`name                               OS version
----                               ----
kead                                windows 2019
hanacockpit                            SLES12SP3`

My second variables, is like

`name                               GB
----                               ----
kead                               54.081582998856902122497558594
hanacockpit                              384.20552698988467454910278320`

As you can see the first column is `name`, as long as the second one has the same name,let's say `kead`,Join `GB` accordingly.

The final output is 

`name                               OS version                GB
----                               ----                      ---
kead                                windows 2019              54.081582998856902122497558594
hanacockpit                            SLES12SP3              384.20552698988467454910278320`

Anyway to do it?

Actually, variable1 and variable2 are from ESXI powercli.

```
# skip connection.

$all=Get-VM | 
   Get-View -Property @("Name", "config.GuestFullName") | 
   Select -Property Name,
       @{N="OS";E={$_.Config.GuestFullName}}

$space =get-vm | Select Name,@{N="disk-size";E= {@([math]::Round($_.ProvisionedSpaceGB / 1))}}
```

Comment: there are at least two merge or join modules in the powershell gallery site that seem able to handle that sort of thing.

Comment: [`$all | Join $space -On Name`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)

Comment: Ah, thanks for you script. I tried it, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not quite what you're asking for, but you could just re-write your command into a one-liner...

Example:

```
   Get-VM | Select Name, @{N="OS";E={$_.ExtensionData.Config.GuestFullName}}, @{N="disk-size";E= {@([math]::Round($_.ProvisionedSpaceGB / 1))}}
```

If you're just looking for the join, my preference has generally been `Join-Object`: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/join-object/